# Running cron every minute on Pantheon with Elysia Cron

Tags: 7, cron

I am on pantheon now and I've never used a cloud host before so I'm used to being able to set cron on the server. This is totally new territory for me. I have some tasks that I need to run every minute and others only during off hours. To do this I have installed Elysia Cron. However, Pantheon does not seem to have the ability to set cron to run every minute so my settings within Elysia Cron are meaningless, but it's really unclear how I'm supposed to make up for that.

Pantheons Cron documentation is laughably vague. It only offered some loose direction without any explanation of really how it ought to be done. One suggestion is to use Pingdom, but there's no indication on how exactly that would work, so I don't want to sign up for a service before I really know how to use it to achieve my goal.

I assume that I just set my Elysia Cron task schedule and then have pingdom 'ping' every minute at the location of Elysia Crons cron file with the key appended like so 'http://site/cron.php?cron_key=XXX'

Am I thinking in the right direction here?

***UPDATE***

I spoke with pantheon support and they confirmed that this was correct.

If you don't already have a pingdom account and want to do this with a free service, freshping will target your cron url as much as once per minute.

Comment: Sounds like it should work to me. But I think you should be asking this question to Pantheon, not here. This is not a Drupal question, it's an infrastructure question, and they are the ones running the infrastructure.

Comment: It involves the use of Drupal and a Drupal module on a Drupal focused host. Seems pretty Drupal related to me. And I doubt I'll be the last to look for this sort of thing here. Nevertheless, I will also contact support. Maybe they'll tell me its too much of Drupal problem and not a pantheon problem as these run-arounds often go.

Comment: Execution of cron is an infrastructure issue, not a software (Drupal) configuration issue. Your problem isn't in configuration of Drupal or the module, it's in how to trigger the cron. As this is infrastructure specific, and not Drupal related, it's off topic for Drupal Answers.

Comment: As for runaround with their staff, I would be surprised - I've always found Pantheon support to be excellent.

Comment: Pantheon does seem to be very good with their chat support. Just a thought, but if Drupal answers remains that pedantic about it's scope it just might 'on-topic' itself into a ghost town and then who does it benefit?

Comment: It's not Drupal Answers, it's Stack Exchange. They decided the format of the site (Q&A), and there are very clearly defined rules of what is on and off topic, with a goal in mind. Unfortunately that does lead to dissatisfaction at times, including with myself. However, usually in such a case, there is a better place to post the question. In the case of your question, Pantheon support is best, then I would go to the Drupal forums next. Stack Exchange is also looking at how to decrease this dissatisfaction.

Comment: @Jaypan I think this is fine personally - you could abstract it out to _What options do I have to run Elysia cron every minute when I can't use server crontab_, but even so I think the specific reference to Pantheon is ok too (we're generally fine with Acquia platform questions, to a point, as well for example). You're not wrong, strictly speaking this is a 3rd party infrastructure issue and off-topic, but it could be useful to a lot of people and it's not too far a stretch to say it's Drupal-related (Drupal has a URL you can ping, not all frameworks do). Just my two cents :)

Comment: Fair enough. And to be honest, I don't like the dissatisfaction that the format of Stack Exchange can bring. But, I also understand why they've chosen to do it this way, and I appreciate they are trying to make it more welcoming.